# How do i check if a string in a set is part of another string in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a beginner in python who has just started learning how to program in python.

I'm trying to test to see if a set has part string in it.

For example if i was to write a program that will ask the user for their mood.

```
posMoodList = { "happy", "good", "great",)
mood = raw_input("How are you feeling? ")
if # function that i want .
    print "you are happy"
```

the function that i want is one that would check if any words in poMoodList will be within the input of the user.

so if the user typed "very happy", "good." or "GREAT!" the program will print "you are happy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to test if a sub-string is present in a string , try this:

```
words = [ "happy", "sad", "good", "bad"]
for word in words:
    if ("happy" in word.lower()):
        print "yes"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: so do i pit the name of the set in between the brackets of values.lower?  so  if (happy in values.lower(set))?

Comment: I am not sure what you want i guess something like the changes i made in answer, note that there are syntax mistakes in your words assignment

Comment: sorry about being unclear, i edited my question to try to make it a bit more clear.  The answer that you provided will only check the [0] place of the list, i wish for it to do that for the whole list.

Comment: @Jack you just have to iterate over the values. I have edited the answer.please accept the it, if it helped.

Comment: Yes! It works! Exactly just what I was looking for, thanks Aameer!